# Can't add event listener after it was removing by "removeEventListener" only on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, event-listener

I'm newbie in js and jquery.

I have the code:

```
function dragEnd(){
    OnDrag = false;
    wrapperHalfWidth = box.parent().width() * settings.animPartofScrennToSlide 
    if (Math.abs(dragLengthX) > wrapperHalfWidth ){
        this.removeEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchstart" : "mousedown"), dragStart, false);
        this.removeEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchmove" : "mousemove"), dragMove, false);
        this.removeEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchend" : "mouseup"), dragEnd, false);
        this.removeEventListener("touchcancel", dragCancel, false);

        var Direction = dragLengthX > 0;
        settings.prevNextClickCallback(outerSlCounter, Direction ? FORWARD : BACK);

        setTimeout(function(){
            this.addEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchstart" : "mousedown"), dragStart, false);
            this.addEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchmove" : "mousemove"), dragMove, false);
            this.addEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchend" : "mouseup"), dragEnd, false);
            this.addEventListener("touchcancel", dragCancel, false);
        }, 500);
        return SlideTo(outerSlCounter + (Direction ? -1 : 1));
    }
    else{   
        dragLengthX = 0;
        box.css({
            '-webkit-transition-timing-function': settings.easingCss,
            '-webkit-transition-duration': settings.animDragTime + 'ms',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + dragLengthX + 'px, 0px, 0px)',
            'transition-timing-function': settings.easingCss,
            'transition-duration': settings.animDragTime + 'ms',
            'transform': 'translate3d(' + dragLengthX + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
        });
    }
    isDragging = false;
    originalX = 0;
};


this.addEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchstart" : "mousedown"), dragStart, false);
this.addEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchmove" : "mousemove"), dragMove, false);
this.addEventListener((useMobileDrag ? "touchend" : "mouseup"), dragEnd, false);
this.addEventListener("touchcancel", dragCancel, false);
```

The borblem is within if (Math.abs(dragLengthX) > wrapperHalfWidth ){...} section. I need to  delete event handlers for the 500ms to prevent other functions (dragStart(event) and dragMove(event)) start.

On desctop it work good. it delete event for the time, when Slidind function is work. But on mobile devices after alert event listeners don't work

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests you using jquery

Comment: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=EfuZANgX - the other functions

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `addEventListener` or `removeEventListener` with jQuery. Use `bind()`/`unbind()` instead.

```
if (Math.abs(dragLengthX) > wrapperHalfWidth ) {
  $(this)
  .bind("touchstart mousedown", dragStart)
  .bind("touchmove mousemove", dragMove)
  .bind("touchend mouseup", dragEnd)
  .unbind("touchcancel");

  var Direction = dragLengthX > 0;
  settings.prevNextClickCallback(outerSlCounter, Direction ? FORWARD : BACK);

  setTimeout(function () {
    $(this)
    .unbind("touchstart mousedown touchmove mousemove touchend mouseup")
    .bind("touchcancel", dragCancel);
  }, 500);

  return SlideTo(outerSlCounter + (Direction ? -1 : 1));
}
```

Although I would find it more elegant if you would use a flag that that tells whether the event handlers should do anything or not, instead of constantly binding and undbinding them.

Comment: @SidorukS: Do you even *use* jQuery in your app? Also "doesn't work" is a pitiful error description, please be more precise.

Comment: I rewrite some parts of TwilightShow ( http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TwilightShow ) plugin and add Drag&Drop functions. http://pastebin.com/EfuZANgX -this part of cod greatly work on desktop browser (Chrome), but when i try it on my iPod Touch that stop working after the first sliding.